# Python module that can remove the OCRed text layer from one pdf file and move it to another?

Tags: python, pdf

I have two pdf files, which are almost the same, except that [the first one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/ocrpdf/1.pdf) has OCRed text and [the other](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/ocrpdf/2.pdf) doesn't, and they have different compressions.

The reason I want to do that is because there is some error in the first file's OCRed text, and the file uses the OCRed text to cover the corresponding image, which makes me unable to know what the correct text is. This is how the second file can help me.

I would like to

- make the first file show the image, with the OCRed text hidden and not covering the image.
- Alternatively, move the OCRed text from the first file to the second.
- Alternatively, remove the OCRed text from the first file, and then re-OCR it, since Adobe Acrobat can't re-OCR a pdf file with OCRed text already.

So I wonder if there is a Python module that can move the OCRed text layer from the first file to the second, while removing the OCRed text layer away from the first file?

If there is no, what languages may have such libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try something with `pdftk` even if it's not Python. Would it be possible to see two such PDF files?

Comment: @lserni: updated. See my post. I didn't find how to do that with pdftk. Thank you if you know how to.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good site for library-shopping questions; questions are supposed to be answerable with a single, objective answer, and that's not true for "what libraries exist for X?" You might want to look at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but since I don't frequent that site, I can't tell you if this is an appropriate question for them; read their help. If not, forums, mailing lists, chat rooms, etc. are usually good for subjective questions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out pdfminer; it's not exactly a user-friendly API, but you should be able to navigate the PDF structure and drop the obstructing text. You can come back with specific questions.

But if it's just a question of hiding the OCR, you may be able to hide it if you open the file in Acrobat; IIRC it has options for showing just the OCR, just the background, or both.

Comment: thanks. But I don't see how pdfminer can move ocred text from one pdf to another, and remove Ocred text from the first one.

Comment: pdfminer is great at extracting content. You should be able to manipulate the structures and (iirc) write them out again, but I was focusing on viewing what's under the image-- I've seen a simple script that will write out all images it finds, which should actually be enough for you since each OCR page is an image. If you want more power to generate your own documents, check out ReportLab, which I've never used but it seems to be the go-to solution for generating PDF with python.

Comment: How to remove OCRed text from a pdf with `pdfminer.six`? Any code snippets will help.

Comment: Sorry, it has been years since I've played with this. Somebody else needs to play with it.. Why don't you take a crack, and when you get as far as you can, ask a new question about your situation.